# How to trust wildcard DNS * in JDK11?

Tags: java, ssl

There is a server which creates HTTPS with certificate with following SAN record:

```
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: localhost
  IPAddress: 127.0.0.1
  URIName: https://localhost
  DNSName: *
]
```

When I try to connect to this server from JDK11 I get following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching host-service found.

In which the `host-service` is the hostname, where the service is located. I double-checked the truststore and it has the required `ca-certs` to trust the certificate. And also the same application works fine when using JDK8.

Can it be that in JDK11 the default behaviour for trusting wildcard DNSs have changed and now it doesn't work?
Also the correlating issue might be that the server runs with `TLSv1.1`. But I configured my client app to run with `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"` so this should work. No default SSL Context was changed in any way and the trustore is located in default path (`/etc/pki/java`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could come up with is to use Insecure SSL as default:

```java
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE;
SslContext sslContext;
SSLContext defaultSSLContext;
try {
    sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                    .trustManager(trustManagerFactory)
                    .build();
    defaultSSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    defaultSSLContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
}
SSLContext.setDefault(defaultSSLContext);
```